# Can not resolve .local domains internal to my office LAN

Tags: debian, dns, mdns

On Linux Debian 9 I am able to resolve a specific local domain e.g. `my.sample-domain.local` using some commands like `nslookup` or `host`, but not with some other commands like `ping` or the Postgres client `psql`.

I think stuff like Network Manager has setup my DNS resolver correctly (the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`), so I am not sure why is this happening?

I checked with a colleague using Windows 10 and they don't have any custom entry in their host file, although in their case the Windows version of `ping` and their database UI for Postgres works as expected resolving the domain into an IP address.

Please see below:

```
$ ping my.sample-domain.local
ping: my.sample-domain.local: Name or service not known

$ host my.sample-domain.local
my.sample-domain.local has address <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>

$ ping -c 5 <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>
PING <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN> (<THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.16 ms
64 bytes from <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.644 ms
64 bytes from <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.758 ms
64 bytes from <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.684 ms
64 bytes from <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.794 ms

--- <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN> ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4056ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.644/0.808/1.160/0.183 ms

$ nslookup my.sample-domain.local
Server:        <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_NAMESERVER>
Address:    <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_NAMESERVER>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    my.sample-domain.local
Address: <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_LOCAL_DOMAIN>


$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain <AN_INTERNAL_DOMAIN>
search <AN_INTERNAL_DOMAIN>
nameserver <THE_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_NAMESERVER>
nameserver <ANOTHER_IP_REPRESENTING_THE_NAMESERVER>
```

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I realized there is an Ubuntu 16 Virtual Machine in the same office LAN, so I logged into it and tried the `ping` command which is working there.

Also that Ubuntu VM does not have any particular custom setting in `/etc/hosts` (the same as my Debian 9 laptop with not customized `/etc/hosts`).

Both the `/etc/resolv.conf` look similar (some shared domains/IPs, some other IPs for the same domain).

However the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is different, so I think there is something going on with this `mdsn4_minimal` and the order of hosts resolution in there like `mdsn4_minimal` coming before `dns`:

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

and on Ubuntu:

```
hosts:      files dns
```

**EDIT 2:**

Both the Ubuntu 16 VM and my Debian 9 laptop are able to resolve that `.local` domain using the `dig` command.

Comment: could be getaddrinfo (`/etc/gai.conf`) or nameserviceswitch (`/etc/nsswitch.conf`), but I only know of these, not about.

Comment: plz show your (sanitised) dig command and output (be sure @server was used)

Comment: This `dig @SERVER my.sample-domain.local +short` gives the output `dig: couldn't get address for 'SERVER': failure` on both the machines. I've tried also `@$SERVER` (although I think that $ was a typo) and I get: `dig: couldn't get address for '': not found`

Comment: You should not use .local on your DNS domains, unless you are talking about ZeroConf. What is your situation?

Comment: I don't manage the LAN network. The IT people does not know anything about Linux, their background is Windows stuff. I have no idea what that "local domain" thing is. I am just trying to connect to a Postgres DB that I don't manage but I am supposed to use to develop a backend application.

Comment: You must talk about the local domain how many times in this thread? What is your local DNS domain? does it really ends in `.local` as you write? It has implications.

Comment: I would like to avoid disclosing potential sensitive information like DNS domains. The "local machine" that was giving troubles is identified by a domain ending with ".local". I know the IT guys are managing a VPN via Cisco hardware, but interacting with them has been historically a waste of my time because they don't understand what I am talking about when mentioning bash commands and common open source tools. So I am not willing to investigate how they setup the network and manage it as long as I can do my job (software developer).

Comment: Answering you, you will understand my insistence in the `.local` thingy when you read my answer.

Comment: I'm going to drop this in here - you don't say which OS the machine you're trying to resolve is running, but if it's a Linux variant, and I hope it's Debian-based, you likely are having trouble with Avahi and friends.  Head on over to https://gist.github.com/davisford/5984768 to get a look at all of the components necessary.  In Apple and Windows land, this functionality is known as "Bonjour" or "Zeroconf".  [This may not help TPPZ, but will aid those who have a slightly borked Avahi install.  It seems as if TPPZ either wants to contact my.sample-domain or my.local - don't add local to a FQDN]

Comment: The issue was that the local machine was a normal VM with a misconfigured `*.local` domain which (as you also pointed out) should be reserved for mDNS (Avahi, Bonjour, Zeroconf and all of that). So by replacing the `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]` with just `mdns4_minimal` in `hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns` I managed to "fix" (ehm.. work around!)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`host` and `nslookup` perform DNS lookups, however most applications use glibc's *Name Service Switch* to decide how host names are looked up.

Your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` might enable mDNS, which might cause the issues when resolving `.local` names. You could change the order in which lookups are made or just remove mDNS service if you think you won't need it.

Your `nsswitch.conf`'s has `mdns4_minimal`, which does [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) lookup (for `.local` names). The `[NOTFOUND=return]` after it causes the lookup to stop and therefore DNS is never used and your application can't resolve the host name. You could either remove the whole `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]`, so mDNS lookups are not used, or just remove the NOTFOUND action so DNS lookup would be made should mDNS lookup fail.

For further details, I recommend checking out the [*Name Service Switch documentation*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Name-Service-Switch.html) .

Comment: I managed to solve the problem changing my local `/etc/nsswitch.conf` moving `dns` before `[NOTFOUND=return]` so the DNS is used before returning. This makes `ping` and `psql` (the Postgres command client) working. However according to the "Multicast DNS" Wikipedia page you suggested this "mDNS LAN .local" setting combined with the `dns` resolution is supposed to violate some sort of "zero-configuration goal" which I am not familiar with. But the workaround at least looks cleaner than some piping bash magic or manual change of `/etc/hosts`. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a real name resolver or a Zeroconf network? `.local` is proposed to be Zeroconf, and all the Debian components are configured to use that by default. If this is not a Zeroconf network, you should prefer `.loc` instead.

Comment: How do I check those things with some commands? I don't manage the IT infrastructure. The IT guys are not very responsive and do not look very much informed about anything outside Windows and Cisco, so usually we don't understand each other and my lack of networking knowledge does not help in asking the right questions to them.

Comment: Your IT guys are incompetent if the really set up a domain called `.local`. Names ending in `.local` are reserved for mDns. LLMNR (Link-local Multicast Name Resolution), which is Microsoft's competing version of multicast DNS, has also adopted this convention: Windows clients will regard `.local` as a non-DNS domain. `.local` is not isolated to some "alien" technology not related to Cisco and Windows.

Comment: You have "*Swtich*" misspelled. It should be "*Switch*" (suggesting an edit to fix the spelling is below the 6 character threshold).

Comment: @JohanMyréen Or there is a legacy network configured according to official recommendations (["At one time, Microsoft at least suggested the use of .local as a pseudo-TLD for small private networks with internal DNS servers,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local#Microsoft_recommendations))

Comment: I wish I could bookmark this answer. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 13):

The bigger problem here is: it is known DNS domain names ending in `.local` should not be used when setting up DNS infra-structures.

`.local` use is reserved for zeroconf/avahi aka bonjour usage, which are parallel services for resolving local names/services besides DNS.

Your internal DNS name service is most certainly having conflicts with zeroconf in some scenarios. Thus the solution in the question you accepted.

In the longer term, your internal network DNS name should not end in `.local`.

PS As an aside, besides DNS, local Microsoft DCs/ADs should not be named `.local` too. You will have strange problems going on if you do that.

> Multicast DNS (mDNS) standard.
>   The Internet Engineering Task Force
>   (IETF) standards-track RFC 6762 (February 20, 2013) reserves the use
>   of the domain name label local as a pseudo-top-level domain for
>   hostnames in local area networks that can be resolved via the
>   Multicast DNS name resolution protocol.

From MS Technet (wikipedia)

> If you have Macintosh client computers that are running the Macintosh
>   OS X version 10.3 operating system or later, … it is recommended that
>   you do not use the .local label for the full DNS name of your internal
>   domain. If you must use the .local label, then you must also configure
>   settings on the Macintosh computers so they can discover other
>   computers on the network

RFC 6762

> Any DNS query for a name ending with ".local." MUST be sent to the
>   mDNS IPv4 link-local multicast address 224.0.0.251 (or its IPv6
>   equivalent FF02::FB).

......

> 4. Reverse Address Mapping
>
>    Like ".local.", the IPv4 and IPv6 reverse mapping domains are also 
>      defined to be link-local:
>
>    Any DNS query for a name ending with "254.169.in-addr.arpa." MUST
>        be sent to the mDNS IPv4 link-local multicast address 224.0.0.251
>        or the mDNS IPv6 multicast address FF02::FB.  Since names under
>        this domain correspond to IPv4 link-local addresses, it is logical
>        that the local link is the best place to find information
>        pertaining to those names.

......

> No special control is needed for enabling and disabling Multicast DNS 
>   for names explicitly ending with ".local." as entered by the user.
>   The user doesn't need a way to disable Multicast DNS for names ending 
>   with ".local.", because if the user doesn't want to use Multicast DNS, they can achieve this by simply not using those names.
>   If a user *does* enter a name ending in ".local.", then we can safely assume the user's intention was probably that it should work.

While not from an official source, I also found this, which has a paragraph that explains the issue nicely: [Stop using .local as the top level domain for your LAN](https://miketelahun.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/stop-using-local-as-the-top-level-domain-for-your-lan/)

> The .local domain is what is called a pseudo-top-level domain.  What
>   does that mean? It means that it’s not an official top level domain
>   usable (routable) on the internet, but it has a semi-official standing
>   because it is used in some applications.
>   In the case of .local it is
>   used by the Multicast Domain Name Service (mDNS).  Hosts that
>   implement this service use .local as their domain names and have their
>   own way of resolving names.  Normally, this wouldn’t be a problem;
>   however, if you also implement DNS on your network with .local as the
>   top-level domain it will cause serious name resolution issues.
>   I’ve
>   seen this happen a lot on Linux systems, and I imagine Apple’s OS X
>   will probably have these issues as well.  Usually, on these types of
>   networks you find that DNS name resolution doesn’t work at all or
>   works only some of the time.  In the end, you end up having to use ip
>   addresses all the time because you don’t know whether a name might
>   resolve or not (which negates the whole point of having a DNS server
>   in the first place).

Comment: Is there a reference somewhere like RFC etc where it is stated that `.local` domains are not for DNS? According to the Wikipedia page I can see mDNS deals only with `.local` domains, but I can not find the other way around is not allowed. In my specific case I figured out that domain has been setup more than 10 years ago by Windows people no longer in the company. The current company managing the infrastructure are mostly useless. Many data scientist work completely unaware of this DNS issue and their code depend on that `.local`, so changing my Debian configuration really solved my problem.

Comment: @TPPZ added some references. It is far from being either a recent or unknown issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a [NBNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP#Name_service) conflicting with a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), so correct that, or edit your [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file, or wrap your commands;

```
NAME=my.sample-domain.local
ping $(host $NAME | perl -pe 's/.* //g')
```

DNS should be inspected with [dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig);

```
dig @$SERVER $NAME +short
```

I'm guessing [host](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host) searches NBNS first (or the other way around).

Comment: host is a dns lookup tool (it ships with bind)

Comment: Thanks, `dig` works and resolves that "local domain". I am currently performing a similar "hack" like yours: `nslookup my.sample-domain.local | grep -A1 my.sample-domain.local | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'` which looks very ugly to me. I need to figure out what is this `/etc/nsswitch.conf` that has been mentioned and what's that DNS ordered resolution like `mdns4_minimal` coming before `dns` with a return `[NOTFOUND=return]` in the middle