# host command takes a long time on .local queries

Tags: systemd-resolved

I'm using `systemd-resolved` configured for mDNS. `host` command takes a long time on `.local` queries. Example:

```
$ time host blah.local
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


real    0m10.019s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.005s
```

The above is a bad query (host `blah.local` does not exist), but the same happens with other queries as well:

```
$ time host valid.local
valid.local has address 192.168.0.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


real    0m10.021s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.011s
```

where it quickly displays the IP of the host and then spends those 10s doing something.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use  "host" command to resolve hostnames with ".local" domains ?

I think this wil not work, cuz "host" command is using  DNS Server to resolve the requested hostname.

Since "valid.local" doesnt have a DNS-Record , this will fail.

Commands like "ping" uses  "/etc/hosts"  to resolve the hostname

Comment: Actually, `host valid.local` resolves fine, just there's a 10s delay after that for some reason that I'm trying to track down.

Comment: as I have answered above. "host" command is using  DNS-Server and you can only resolve it if you have changed the configuration of "/etc/resolve.conf" .  
If ypu wnat to know what happens to your request , try 
strace host valiud.local

you can also take a look at similar post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457166/can-not-resolve-local-domains-internal-to-my-office-lan