# How to setup a bind9 server for a private home network

Tags: dns, bind9

My end goal is to setup a DNS server to use in the network 10.0.0.0/24, the network consists of a TP-Link home switch and a workstation running runtu(ubuntu)linux and a laptop connect to that switch, the DNS server should be used to resolve ip address in the network 10.0.0.0/24 only

the server `10.0.0.1` runs `ssh`,`dhcp` and hopefully `dns`

I installed bind9 and created the following setup

`/etc/bind/named`

```
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "workstation.local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/forward.workstation.local";
};

zone "10.0.0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/reverse.workstation.local"; # 10.0.0.0/24
};
```

`/etc/bind/forward.workstation.local`

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.workstation.localhost.
@   IN  A   10.0.0.1
```

`/etc/bind/reverse.workstation.local`

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.workstation.local.
1   IN  PTR ns1.workstation.local.
```

when trying the command `host workstation.local` I get the output
`Host workstation.local not found: 2(SERVFAIL)`

How to properly setup the dns server so that the laptop can connect to the ip 10.0.0.1 using the `workstation.local`
This is my first time setting up a dns server in linux, I could use all the help possible

Update
I tried to use `home` instead of `local` but I still can't reach the server from the laptop

Comment: see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457166/can-not-resolve-local-domains-internal-to-my-office-lan/457525#457525

Comment: Though technically you might be able to pull it off, I've never seen subdomains on .local. It is supposed to be a top level domain valid only for the local link. And it should work without configuration if you use avahi-mdns for example. Trying to set that up might run into problems, for example resolution in Linux might go to mdns_minimal first (in `/etc/resolv.conf`) instead of your server.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I changed `local` to `home` but i still can't reach the server

Comment: I fear this question might be a bit too big to get a proper answer. Setting up and configuring any server is a process with many steps... My best hint though is to use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) a lot. Once you collect and analyze pcaps, you know what's really happening.